# create php element with angularJS route link

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have created this html element using php :

```
 echo
     "<button 
      type ='button' class='login-btn login' 
      onclick = 'location.href='#!login';'> 
            Login
      </button>";
```

and when I click on it I want to get redirected to a login page using angularJS . If it is a regular html element it works succesfully but since I modify the `'' , " "` to create it with php my link does not work .

I get the error :`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` for location.href

This is my angularJS file for a more detailed view  :

angModule.js

```
const app = angular.module("myApp" , ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(($routeProvider)=>{
  $routeProvider
    .when("/" , {templateUrl:"main.php"})
    .when("/login" , {templateUrl : "login.php"})
    .when("/register" , {templateUrl : "register.php"});
});
```

I would appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the quotes in `onclick = 'location.href='#!login';'`:

```
echo
     "<button 
      type ='button' class='login-btn login' 
      onclick = 'location.href=\"#!login\";'> 
            Login
      </button>";
```

(The first quote from `'#!login'` terminates the one from `'location.href=`)

More on PHP strings: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php